# Is If let Evaluated Differently from If Statement?

Tags: swift, if-statement

Is `if let` kind of `if` statement, or is `if let` different?

Does the compiler treat `if let` and `if` statement differently?

Comment: From the language reference https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/if-statement: *"The value of any condition in an if statement must be of type Bool or a type bridged to Bool. The condition can also be an optional binding declaration, as discussed in Optional Binding."*

Answer (score 0):

`if let` is for unwrapping optional values.

`if` is for evaluating a condition

```
var example: String? = "rick"
if let name = example{
    print(name) //name is the unwrapped version of example
}
```

If example is `nil` (no value), then the `if let` statement will fall through and the code inside of it will not run.

```
var example: Bool = true
if example{
    print("Example is true")
} else{
    print("Example is false")
}
```